# wordpress / woocommerce - unset payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i try to unset several payment gateways based on conditions. i do my first steps with this, so i tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'gateway_disable' );

function gateway_disable( $available_gateways ) {
   if ( ! is_admin() ) {
      if ( isset( $available_gateways['invoice'] )) {
         unset( $available_gateways['invoice'] );
   }
}
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

I expect that invoice never comes up. if i go to the checkout invoice is not shown. after a few seconds the cart seems to be reloaded automatically and then invoice comes up.

Why and how to solve it? I don´t undestand what i am doing wrong...

thanks in advance.